# Int64RangePartitionInformation - how can I create object? I want to use object in my unit test

Tags: c#, service-fabric-stateful

Int64RangePartitionInformation - how can I create object? I want to use object in my unit test. When I attempt to create object using 
var c = new Int64RangePartitionInformation();
compiler throws me error 'Int64RangePartitionInformation' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

I don't see any constructor for this class either. How this type of non-instantiable class is implemented? If I want to , how can i instantiate it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution, although not very nice, is:

```
FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(
    typeof(Int64RangePartitionInformation)) as Int64RangePartitionInformation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're testing, you could create a mock and use that. For instance with Moq, you could do

```
var partitionInformation = new Mock<Int64RangePartitionInformation>().Object;
DoSomething(partitionInformation);
```

Comment: Int64RangePartitionInformation is sealed so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to mock Int64RangePartitionInformation, you can use the ServiceFabric.Mocks library and create mock of Int64RangePartitionInformation as

```
var mockPartitionInfo = MockQueryPartitionFactory.CreateIntPartitonInfo();
```

NuGet package: `ServiceFabric.Mocks`

[GitHub link](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks)